# HelpProvider in checbox list specific item (C#)

Tags: c#, object, checkbox, checkboxlist

I'm making an app which uses a checkbox list. Each item has to have a "description", so I decided to make it with a HelpProvider. But the problem is that when I make a loop that should fill all the checkboxes in checkbox list with a helprovider, Visual tells me that it is an object which cannot be converted into System.Windows.Forms.Control

Any ideas for a workaround?

```
for (int i = 0; i < CheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
     this.AdditionalInfos.SetShowHelp(CheckedListBox.Items[i], true);
     this.AdditionalInfos.SetHelpString(CheckedListBox.Items[i], "example description");
}
```

Comment: Can you add more infos about the error? Which line, the exact message? Thank you.

Comment: As I said, the compiler gives this exact error: "CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control", so I guess that items from checkedlistbox were never meant to recieve HelpProvider infos. Tho what I am looking for is a workaround.

Comment: What's the type of your CheckListBox items (when you added them)? Are they simple strings?

Comment: Yep. They are added with 1 argument which is string.

Comment: You can't do this with HelpProvider.  Instead implement the HelpRequested event for the control and call Help.ShowHelp() yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason you get that error is because and `SetShowHelp` and `SetHelpString` expect a `Control` object (a Button, a Label, etc...) but you're giving it a `string` which can't be handled by the `HelpProvider`.

I believe that in order to do what you want to do, you'll have to write a custom thing (since the elements of the `CheckBoxList` aren't Controls). You can either write a "complex" thing that can show descriptions on hover or you can just listen to the `SelectedIndexChanged` and show a description on a label or something.